# Does ModelBuilder need to use variable to define projection and then re-project?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, modelbuilder

I am trying to build a Model in ModelBuilder to create two different process raster datasets:

1. One set is to define a raster dataset to set a  WGS 84 projection; and then
2. the second set is to take the define projection raster datasets to reprojection to NAD UTM 83 to a new folder.

Do I need to create a variable to copy from a define projection raster set and then
Reprojection raster dataset to NAD UTM 83?

What is the correct variable tool should I use to perform to connect them?

BTW, I have to do this with a lot of raster datasets and do the same thing.

Comment: Can you perhaps edit your Question to explain what you mean by "two groups"?  A ModelBuilder screenshot may well help me to picture what you are describing.

Comment: Is the issue here perhaps how you create names during this process?  If so, then you probably need to just look at Iterate Rasters and Parse Path.

Comment: Have you got access to FME? It is probably easier to use GtransReproject there.

Comment: Martin, Are you talking about FME a separate program or is it within ArcGIS 10.1 Extension ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to create "standalone" variables to hold them.  In your model, why can't you just expose the [input and output coordinate systems](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007q000000) as model parameter's?  See [Creating model parameters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000003z000000).

Try this:

- Right-click on the "Project Raster" box and choose Make Variable-> From Parameter-> Output Coordinate System.
- Then r-click on the parameter circle and choose "Model Parameter".